# Add calculated column in Snowfalke

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, alter

Again, I can't seem to find a simple way to do this.
But I've been coding for a while now and potentially I'm just tired and losing it!

```
SELECT 
case when "colA" = '1' OR "colB" = 1 then 1
    else 0
end as "colc"
FROM t1
```

How do I add this new column to t1, preserving the order etc.?

I know I can run

```
ALTER t1 ADD COLUMN colc
```

but how do I populate the values correctly?

Comment: I don't think Snowflake supported computed columns.  You would need to use a view.

Answer (score 4):

Despite the documentation you can find around, it is actually possible to create computed columns. Here is an example:

```
create or replace table computedColTest (id bigint, id2 bigint, derived bigint as (id * id2));
insert into computedColTest values (3, 5);
select * from computedColTest;
```

The result is:

[image]

However, I don't think it is possible to directly translate the logic you need as you can't seem to be able to use a logical operator within it. You can however adapt it a bit to your situation and translate your switch into a mathematical operation that is compatible.

Answer (score 2):

I think 'Virtual Columns' is how derived columns are known in Snowflake.
Check this out:

```
CREATE 
OR REPLACE TABLE Virtual_Column_Example (
    colA INT
    , colB INT
    , derived INT AS ( IFF(colA = 1 or colB = 1, 1, 0) )
);

INSERT INTO Virtual_Column_Example 
    VALUES (0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1),(2, 2);

SELECT * FROM Virtual_Column_Example;

/*
---------------------
colA | colB | derived
---------------------
   0 |    0 |      0
   1 |    1 |      1
   1 |    2 |      1
   2 |    1 |      1
   2 |    2 |      0
---------------------
*/
```

Answer (score -2):

I actually found a way that works well, just use `UPDATE`

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD COLUMN "col3" INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

UPDATE t1
SET "col3"= 1
WHERE "col1" = 1 OR "col2" = 1;
```

Comment: This only updates the column values one time when you execute the query. It doesn't preserve any logic after any record is updated, deleted or created.